# Trying to create docker image at command prompt getting docker build error

Tags: windows, docker, containers

Created dotnet core mvc application. Tried to create docker image for Windows containers. When I execute docker build command getting below error.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\dockertestwindows\dockertestwindows.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.404\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\src\dockertestwindows\dockertestwindows.csproj]
The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore "dockertestwindows/dockertestwindows.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1


My docker file is 
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerWindowsCore/DockerWindowsCore.csproj", "DockerWindowsCore/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerWindowsCore/DockerWindowsCore.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerWindowsCore"
RUN dotnet build "DockerWindowsCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerWindowsCore.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerWindowsCore.dll"]
```

Comment: Did you check out this link? https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/247

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: added my docker file code

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to VPN issue is resolved. I think its firewall issue.